# VSCode Quickfix / Code Actions for Apex files not working

Tags: ide, visualstudiocode

**TL;DR**

How can I enable (or customize) quick fixes/code actions for Apex classes in VS code?

**Problem**

Quick fix actions like extraction via `ctrl + .` or `F2` for file-wide renaming aren't working. Below is an example in a Java file:

[image]

And below is what is happening in Apex.

[image]

Does anyone know why these features are disabled, and where I can go to try to re-enable them?

Things I have tried:

- Restart vs code
- Uninstall and reinstall the salesforce CLI
- Uninstall and reinstall the salesforce extension pack